# Firebase sign in with google for web not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-signin

I was working on a react project in which I wanted to implement google sign in so I used firebase and wrote the following code:

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "****",
authDomain: "***",
projectId: "***",
storageBucket: "***",
messagingSenderId: "***",
appId: "***",
measurementId: "***"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app;
```

Creating Context to make the function accessible in the whole application:

```
import React from 'react';
import FirebaseContext from './FirebaseContext';
import { auth } from '../Firebase/firebase';
import { signInWithRedirect,GoogleAuthProvider,createUserWithEmailAndPassword   } from "firebase/auth";

const FirebaseState = (props)=>{

    const reactSignup = (email,password)=>{
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
    }

    const googleSignin = ()=>{
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

        return signInWithRedirect(auth,provider);
    }
    return(
        <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{reactSignup,googleSignin}}>{props.children}</FirebaseContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default FirebaseState;
```

Calling the function on the desired button click

```
const {googleSignin} = useContext(FirebaseContext);
const handleGoogleSignin = async()=>{
    try{
      console.log("Sign in attempted");
      await googleSignin();
      history.push("/main");
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Now the problem is that whenever I am running application using npm run start and the button is clicked it does not redirect for sign in but when the application is stopped then it is able to redirect but as my application is no more running that is of no use.

[30 sec screen recording of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1suZlL9JJtXGGyx8pEBd1_xG60X-z6Bgw/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Do you try to change **signInWithRedirect** to **signInWithPopup** ?

So

```
import React from 'react';
import FirebaseContext from './FirebaseContext';
import { auth } from '../Firebase/firebase';
import { signInWithPopup,GoogleAuthProvider,createUserWithEmailAndPassword   } from "firebase/auth";

const FirebaseState = (props)=>{

    const reactSignup = (email,password)=>{
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
    }

    const googleSignin = ()=>{
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

        return signInWithPopup(auth,provider);
    }
    return(
        <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{reactSignup,googleSignin}}>{props.children}</FirebaseContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default FirebaseState;
```

**Alternative Idea**

Detact signInWithRedirect from Context and use the funct directly in your component function like this:

```
import { auth, provider } from '../../config';
import { signInWithPopup } from '@firebase/auth';
import { Button } from '@chakra-ui/button';

export default function Signup() {
  const loginWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={loginWithGoogle}>Signin With Google</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Alternative Idea 2**

```
Go to Firebase Panel > Authentication > Sign-in Method
```

Check your domain, if your domain is in the list delete and add again. Else add your domain.

Comment: Yes I have tried using this but the same problem persists when the server is running the popup does not come up but when the server is closed then the popup appears

Comment: @TusharVerma Hey Tushar i updated my answer. Please , check other alternative ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answers actually after hit and trial I figured out that the problem was that my button is inside a form and whenever the button is clicked actually the page gets refreshed(due to the default behaviour of foms) so I just added event.preventDefault() in my function and it worked fine

Comment: I am very happy that you solved the problem.